# Как сделать виджет Text однострочным

Tags: python, функции, tkinter, text

Вот примерный исходник:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk.Tk()

c = Tk.Canvas(root)
c.place(x=-5,y=-5)

class Element_Text():
    def __init__(self, number_place, url_name):
        self.name = Tk.Text(c, bg="white", font=("Calibri", 10));
        self.name.insert("1.0", str(url_name))
        self.name.place(x=33, y=25 + 25 * number_place, height=20, width=128)
    def del_element(self):
        self.name.destroy()
    def get_val(self):
        return self.name.get("1.0", Tk.END)


element_text_1 = Element_Text(1,"vk.com")
element_text_2 = Element_Text(3,"ok.com")

root.mainloop()
```

Как сделать так, чтоб у виджета Text была максимальная длина текста до конца виджета, и при превышении лимита выдавалась ошибка:

```
messagebox.showerror("Ошибка!", "Максимальное кол-во символов превышено")
```

Или сделать по другому. Использовать функцию или параметр который, непользволяет
переносить текст на другую строку, только как сделать это?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более простой вариант это использовать `Entry` вместо `Text` (не надо подстраивать высоту виджета)

```
from tkinter import messagebox, Entry, Tk, StringVar, END, Canvas

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root)
c.place(x=-5, y=-5)


class Element_Text():
    def __init__(self, number_place):
        self.name = Entry(c, bg="white", font=("Calibri", 10), width=20)
        self.name.place(x=33, y=25 + 25 * number_place)
        self.name.bind("<KeyPress>", self.a)


    def a(self, event):
        if len(self.name.get()) >= 20:
            self.name.delete(20, END)
            messagebox.showerror("Ошибка!", "Максимальное кол-во символов превышено")


element_text_1 = Element_Text(1)
element_text_2 = Element_Text(3)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Или можно как предложил [@insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796267/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-text-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC/796286#comment1256716_796286) (что по сути является более правильным ответом)

```
from tkinter import messagebox, Entry, Tk, StringVar, END


def callback(sv):
    if len(e.get()) >= 20:
        e.delete(20, END)
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка!", "Максимальное кол-во символов превышено")


root = Tk()
sv = StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback(sv))
e = Entry(root, textvariable=sv, width=20)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Через ctrl+v если вставить, ограничение не сработает. Лучше реагировать на изменение текста в поле, как вот здесь, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549535/4752653

Comment: @insolor спасибо подрдактировал

Comment: Я все-таки имел в виду привязывание переменной к текстовому полю, и реагирование на ее изменение. Сейчас в комментарии ссылка уже про это)

Comment: @insolor через телефон не удобно редактировать) и обновления комментария не сразу

Comment: @оаавирыыва а в чем проблема? так же через `instert`

Comment: Я не знал как в Entry вставлять текст, покапался в коде и нашел, и заменил Text на Entry. И потом все пошло и поехало. Спасибо вам что мне напомнили заного про Entry